# Merging Financial Data

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to figure out how to take the financial information(income statement, balance sheet, and cash flow from yahoo finance.  I have a list called symbols which has all the ticker numbers (see code below). Ultimately I want to end up with a csv which has rows the 4 years (2018, 2017, 2016, 2015) concatenated.
'''
I can do this manually, but what I want to do is automate it so that I can return a .csv file which has all the relevant information (77 columns and 4*#ticker symbol rows) 
[image]
Turn the image above to:
[image]

I have figured out how to scrape the data from yahoo using a scraper.

```
from lxml import html
from lxml import html
import requests

import numpy as np

import pandas as pd
def scrape_table(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    table = tree.xpath('//table')
    assert len(table) == 1

    df = pd.read_html(lxml.etree.tostring(table[0], method='html'))[0]

    df = df.set_index(0)
    df = df.dropna()
    df = df.transpose()
    df = df.replace('-', '0')

    # The first column should be a date
    df[df.columns[0]] = pd.to_datetime(df[df.columns[0]])
    cols = list(df.columns)
    cols[0] = 'Date'
    df = df.set_axis(cols, axis='columns', inplace=False)

    numeric_columns = list(df.columns)[1::]
    df[numeric_columns] = df[numeric_columns].astype(np.float64)

    return df



def merge_IS_BS_CF(df_IS, df_BS, df_CF):
    #merge the three financial statements - Income statement, balance sheet, cash flow into one dataframe
    #return the dataframe
    df_merge_IS_BS = pd.merge(df_IS, df_BS, on='Date')
    df_merge_IS_BS_CF = pd.merge(df_merge_IS_BS, df_CF, on='Date')
    return df_merge_IS_BS_CF

symbols = ['AAPL', 'MFT.NZ']

financials = {}
#create a dictionary of ticker names and their respective statements' urls
for symbol in symbols:
    financials[symbol] = ['https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + symbol + '/financials?p=' + symbol, 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + symbol + '/balance-sheet?p=' + symbol, 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + symbol + '/cash-flow?p=' + symbol]
print (financials['AAPL'][0])
data = pd.DataFrame([])
```

the result that I get is that it doesn't concatenate the next ticker data onto the pandas data frame.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is unreadable. You cant expect people to go through your code and "debug" it for you, without even having data. Best way is to 1. start with an example dataframe 2. Explain what you try to achieve. 3. Include an expected output in the form of a dataframe as well. 4. Explain whats not working right now.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and fixing the errors I had in showing my code. I added some images so hopefully it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I figured this out on my own.  Just for the next person, my mistake was not realising that I had to save the appended dataframe.

```
symbols = ['AAPL', 'MFT.NZ']
financials = {}
#create a dictionary of ticker names and their respective statements' urls
for symbol in symbols:
    financials[symbol] = ['https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + symbol + '/financials?p=' + symbol, 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + symbol + '/balance-sheet?p=' + symbol, 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + symbol + '/cash-flow?p=' + symbol]
print (financials['AAPL'][0])
data = pd.DataFrame()

for f in financials:
    print (f)
    df_income_statement = scrape_table(financials[f][0])
    df_balance_sheet = scrape_table(financials[f][1])
    df_cash_flow = scrape_table(financials[f][2])
    oldmerge = merge_IS_BS_CF(df_income_statement, df_balance_sheet, df_cash_flow)
    #print (oldmerge)
    data = data.append(oldmerge)
```